# Why doesn't this site have a Google logo for their use of Google Maps? I want to do this. How?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, google-maps

How can I remove (assuming it's legal) the Google logo and "terms of use" wording from my Google Maps like this site did:  [**http://fwix.com/**](http://fwix.com/)

**UPDATE**

This is in fact the standard Google Map as well. Fwix calls for the map the standard way, by using `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false` as well as the map itself even states that "map data 2010 Google". It just appears they have used CSS and/or JavaScript to hide the Google logo and "terms of use" link from being displayed on the map.

Comment: See their [terms of use](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html), section 9.4: "Content provided to you through the Service may contain the trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand features of Google.... You may not delete or in any manner alter these." </snip>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the logo, you are breaking [9.4](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_9_3) of the terms of service.

> 9.4 Attribution Content provided to you through the Service may contain
> the trade names, trademarks, service
> marks, logos, domain names, and other
> distinctive brand features of Google,
> its partners, or other third party
> rights holders of content indexed by
> Google. You may not delete or in any
> manner alter these trade names,
> trademarks, service marks, logos,
> domain names, and other distinctive
> brand features.

Looks like a bad idea. It is a free service [for the most part], if you do not like it, pay for the rights to use the maps and code your own.

Comment: You can also license to use Google Maps. Do you think that licensing it allows them to do this?

Comment: Look at 5.2 http://support.google.com/enterprise/doc/gme/terms/maps_purchase_agreement.html

Answer (score 4):

They seem to be using some CSS shenanigans to hide the "Terms of use" link. If you look closely, there is always a closing `-` after the copyright notice.

It is most likely a violation of Google's Terms of use that webmasters agree to when generating the API key. I would not recommend doing this.

**Update:** This is the relevant CSS that hides the link (as said, don't try this at home! ):

```
#map a, #map p {
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
text-indent:-9999px;
z-index:400;
}
```

Comment: Good point. Too bad it seems I got excited about something that appears to be breaking the terms of use :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they just moved the logo and stuff using javascript/css out of the visible area. To my knowledge it isn't possible to do this legally.

UPDATE:

According to the [Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html), section 7.4(b)(viii):

> [In using Google Brand Features, you
>   will not] remove, distort or alter any
>   element of a Google Brand Feature
>   (this includes squeezing, stretching,
>   inverting, discoloring, etc.).

Comment: You can also license to use Google Maps. Do you think that licensing it allows them to do this?

Comment: @user I assume if they bought a license, they would hardly have to hide the logo in this kludgy way.

Comment: Good point. Too bad it seems I got excited about something that appears to be breaking the terms of use :(